# How do I detect the output voltage of the charging controller?

Tags: battery-charging, cortex-m4, voltage-detector

[image]My project uses Li-ion battery charger LTC4099 (https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/4099fd.pdf). And S6E2DH FM4 microcontroller (https://www.cypress.com/file/224786/download). I want to detect the presence of the ouput voltage VOUT of the charging controller (in the attached picture) using the microcontroller. What are some sensible ways to do it? Please let me know. Thanks.

PS: I want to measure using a voltage divider but dont exactly get it because the VOUT of the battery charge controller is varying but not always constant. Isn't it?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. It is polite to include links to datasheets (not Amazon or Ali-what's-it ad pages) for the devices in question in your question. Better again is to include a screenshot or image of the LTC4099 pinout and what options you have considered as a solution. That way we don't all have to follow links to understand your question and you are much more likely to get good interest in your question.

Comment: Show a schematic too.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I just added info to make it more clear. Please go through and kindly help. Thanks.

Comment: You need to indicate how the microcontroller is connected to the circuit above i.e. how it receives power.